# how to write unit test back navigation

Tags: swift, unit-testing

this error -->
No matches found for Find: Elements matching predicate '"< Back" IN identifiers' from input {(
    NavigationBar, 0x60c0001922e0, traits: 35192962023424, identifier: 'papon_Workshop03.BTSView'
)}

this code unit test -->

```
let buttonTest = XCUIApplication()
buttonTest.buttons["Chong Nonsi"].tap()
buttonTest.tables.cells.staticTexts["Wutthakat"].tap() 
buttonTest.navigationBars.______i want to know.what should use method_________
```

first I select button

[image]

second tap() in "Wutthakat"

[image]

and last I don't know method process of select navigationBar.Back

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can write by this my code

```
             let app = XCUIApplication()
             app.buttons["Chong Nonsi"].tap()
              app.tables/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.staticTexts["Wutthakat"]/*[[".cells.staticTexts[\"Wutthakat\"]",".staticTexts[\"Wutthakat\"]"],[[[-1,1],[-1,0]]],[0]]@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/.tap()

              app.navigationBars["papon_Workshop03.BTSView"].buttons["Back"].tap()
             XCTAssertTrue(app.buttons["Wutthakat"].exists)
```

Comment: I tried your answer but I still get the above error.